# Django Rest Framework API Client Custom Header

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-tests, drf-extensions

I am trying to use bulk update from drf-extensions. To make it work, there is a safeguard requiring the header "X-BULK-OPERATION": 'true'. I can get the application working using curl or my angular app, but in my tests I am trying to use `rest_framework.test.APIClient` to send the partial_update request, but every time I get a 400 response, and when debugging the request, I am getting

```
ipdb> response.data
{'detail': "Header 'X-BULK-OPERATION' should be provided for bulk operation."}
```

This is the request I am trying to use in my test

```
    response = self.client.patch(
        '/api/v1/db_items/?active=True',
        json.dumps(data),
        content_type='application/json',
        **{X-BULK-OPERATION: 'true'}
    )
```

Is there a way to set headers on an APIClient request?

I've even tried changing the header name and setting it in credentials with

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_BULK_OPERATION='true')
```

but I get the same error every single time

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The answer is extremely poorly documented, but it seems django does its own parsing of the headers passed in. I successfully did this by changing my code to be

```py
response = self.client.patch(
    "/api/v1/db_items/?active=True",
    json.dumps(data),
    content_type="application/json",
    HTTP_X_BULK_OPERATION="true",
)
```

Note the `HTTP_` prefix. This is recognized by the Django `client` and translated to a HTTP header with the key `X-BULK-OPERATION` and the value `"true"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful. A note on the documentation, DRF states their API Client extends the Django Client where they link to it's docs. It is there, Django explains adding headers with a HTTP_ prefix. I didn't notice it the first time while struggling with this very thing.

Answer (score 10):

Your initial solution is almost correct; you are just missing the "X" portion of your header field name:

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_X_BULK_OPERATION='true')
```

This worked for me with other arbitrary header keys.

Answer (score 8):

Or you can just pass it as a *kwarg* of request.
It is important to add `HTTP_` prefix to your header (`HTTP_MyHeader`, instead of `MyHeader`):

```
response = self.client.patch(
    '/api/v1/db_items/?active=True',
    json.dumps(data),
    content_type='application/json',
    'HTTP_X_BULK_OPERATION'='true'
)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you'r using
standard header like HTTP_ACCEPT(Accept header) or HTTP_AUTHORIZATION (AUTHORIZATION header)
you can also use these two ways

DRF doc recommends first way
and if you want to apply header to all request use first way

1-

```
client.credentials(HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json; version=1.0')

response = self.client.patch(
        '/api/v1/db_items/?active=True',
        json.dumps(data),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
```

2-

```
response = self.client.patch(
    '/api/v1/db_items/?active=True',
     json.dumps(data),
     content_type='application/json',
     HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json; version=1.0'
    )
```