# Adding custom header to DRF test APIClient

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I need to add a custom header to the APIClient for a test.
I have tried to follow this section of the official [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs)

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
```

Following the official docs results in an error because the name has hyphens
This raises a syntax error because the name is not valid.

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HEADER-WITH-HYPHEN='Token ' + token.key)
```

I also tried using `from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient` but this needs the url to include http which isn't possible because the server doesn't run while testing.

It also isn't possible to change the header name to something more pythonic :|

Comment: Hmm according to the source code it's  using kwargs, hence why it's not working with hyhen https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py

Comment: Or this maybe answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073763/django-rest-framework-api-client-custom-header?rq=2

Comment: Thanks for your help @BDurand
I just found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this `client.credentials(HTTP_header_with_hyphen=token)` will evaluate to `{"Header-With-Hyphen": token}` in the request header.